# How to check when data is changed in ALV specific field?

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I need to check a field in my ALV, set as editable, when it is changed.

This is my `fieldcat` with the concerned field set as editable:

```
  CLEAR wfieldcat.
  wfieldcat-fieldname     = 'PERDEVA'.
  wfieldcat-ref_fieldname = 'PERDEVA'.
  wfieldcat-ref_tabname   = 'IT_DEVALUATS'.
  wfieldcat-seltext_s     = 'Devaluat'.
  wfieldcat-seltext_m     = 'Devaluat'.
  wfieldcat-seltext_l     = 'Devaluat'.
  wfieldcat-ddictxt       = 'M'.
  wfieldcat-edit          = 'X'.            "<==========
  APPEND wfieldcat TO p_fieldcat.
```

Once the field is changed by user, I need to check some conditions for value, and if they are not accomplished, just call my own `refresh` form.

Probably there are some Function Modules or Methods to do that, but every documentation that I found refers to S/4HANA and I'm using R/3.

**Edit**:
As I said in comments "CHECK_CHANGED_DATA"  is the Function Module that i was looking for, and @Suncatcher provides the threat with a properly usage [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763326/read-alv-changes-after-user-input).

Comment: Ok, i found [CHECK_CHANGED_DATA](https://www.se80.co.uk/oo-abap/i/if_g/if_glmwb_bp_model-check_changed_data.htm)'s method as a possible solution. I'm going to try to implement it

Comment: Perhaps this may help you [ALV grid edit events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405640/mark-checkboxes-in-alv-output-grid-as-selected/46405902#46405902)

Comment: @Suncatcher thanks! There are the example that I need :)

Answer (score 2):

You should see the demo programs, Go to SE38 tcode and you can write BALV* or BCALV* press f4. You can see check_changed_data implement examples.

Comment: To be exact: `BCALV_EDIT_03` - Verification of modified cells. But anyway this example collection is really good starting point with explanations in code.

Comment: Please [provide context for links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), i.e. a brief explanation about how these demo programs solve the OP question.

Comment: Note that this question is a duplicated question (as already noticed by Suncatcher) and I have just added a minimal reproducible example to this other question/answer to demonstrate how this method can work (not optimal but at least minimal).

Comment: @SandraRossi yes, that thread is what I was looking for :)